# Can you use push and pop inside a function?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am making a program to print a string received from the input in reversed order. However, I keep getting Invalid memory reference (SIGSEGV) error. I know the issue is when I push ax but I dont know why I'm getting it. I tried to make another test program to test out the push instruction and found out that if I use push inside a function/procedure that I call, I get the above error. It doesn't happen with a normal block.

```
;nasm 2.13.02

section .data

section .bss
    myData resb 1
    temp resb 2
    counter resb 1

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov [counter], word 1
main:
    call read_data
    ;call FlipString
    jmp end
    
read_data:
    mov eax,3            ; The system call for read
    mov ebx,0            ; File descriptor 1 - standard output
    mov ecx,myData        ; Put the variable here
    mov edx,1     ; put variable's size here
    int 80h              ; Call the kernel
    
    mov bl, [myData]
    cmp bl, '.'    
    jne pushStack
ret

pushStack:
    mov ax, 0
    mov ax, [myData]
    push ax
    add [counter], byte 1
    jmp read_data

FlipString:
    pop ax
    mov [temp], ax
 
    mov eax,4            ; The system call for write (sys_write)
    mov ebx,1            ; File descriptor 1 - standard output
    mov ecx,counter         ; Put the variable here
    mov edx,1            ; put variable's size here
    int 80h              ; Call the kernel
    
    sub [counter], byte 1
    mov al, [counter]
    cmp al, 0
    jg FlipString    
ret

end:
    mov eax,1            ; The system call for exit (sys_exit)
    mov ebx,0            ; Exit with return code of 0 (no error)
    int 80h;
```

Comment: `mov ebx,0 ; File descriptor 1 - standard output` Umm?

Comment: My apology. I paste the wrong comment.

Comment: When `.` is encountered, you will `ret` without having popped the stack of what you pushed.  Push and pop are fine within a function, but they must stay balanced.

Comment: So I have to pop it before leaving the function?

Comment: Yes.  `ret` pops its return value off the stack, so when you `ret`, the stack pointer must be at exactly the same location as when the function was entered.  The best way to do that is to design your code so that push and pops always come in pairs.  If you want to abort without popping, then save the value of `esp` in another register upon entry, and restore it from that register before returning.

Comment: Thinking about your question title, very little code is not part of a function (e.g. process and system-call entry points), yet `push`/`pop` are widely used even in compiler-generated code, and compilers only generate code for functions. So I'm surprised you phrased the question as if the answer might be "no", rather than just that you're using it *wrong*.  (`ret` is basically `pop eip`, so ESP has to be pointing at your return address when it runs.  Use a debugger to single-step your code)

Comment: You're also mixing operand-sizes in weird ways, like doing a 2-byte `word` load in `mov ax, [myData]`, so you're getting the `resb 1` byte and the first byte of the 2-byte `temp` space you reserved.  Did you mean `movzx ax, byte [myData]`, or mean to reserve more space?  Also storing 2 bytes to `[counter]` where you only reserved 1, but nothing follows it so it happens to work to use `.bss` space out to the end of the page.